# Regular expression should match white space only if some test is entered -JS

Tags: regex

I'm currently using this regex  `/^[A-Za-z_ ]{3,20}$/;` for validating name in my website . The Problem with this expression is , it also matches three or more spaces ! Of i didnt enter any name and enter just hit space three times it validates ! I want to validate white spaces only if i enter some text . How to do this ?

Comment: "some text" means how mnay letters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_ ]{2,19}$/;
```

if you use this, then the space/undescore will be accepted only after a letter is already entered.

Comment: @anubhava yes, but the op is only concerned with the inital spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[a-z][\w ]{1,18}[a-z]$/i
```

Which will NOT allow spaces at the start or in the end.

Comment: what about numbers sir, it will allow numbers too

Comment: Yes it will because OP didn't write any requirement for disallowing numbers.

Comment: Thanks ! But i dont want numbers to be validated !

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your question.